# HTML signature in gmail - weird space

Tags: html, gmail, html-email, newsletter

I'm trying to make a signature for email (Lotus Notes). However, while it looks fine on Lotus (yay) I'm getting this space between the title and email address on Gmail.

And I have no idea why that is.

Picture of how it looks on Lotus Notes:

[image: ![enter image description here]

And how it looks on gmail:

[image]

Here link to a Fiddle Doesn't work properly as it does on email (don't know why):

```html
    <table  border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    
        <tr  align="left">
            <td   valign="top" width="100" ><a href="https:/URL.eu"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/XCyNdd6.png" alt="logo" ></a></td>
            <td    valign="top" width="700" ><strong><span style=" display:table;font-family: Arial; font-size: medium; "><font size="3" face="Arial">John Doe Smith</font></span></strong>         
    
                <table align="left" width="100%" cellpadding="2", cellspacing="0">
    
    
                    <tr >   
                        <td><a  href="https:/URL-example.eu"><span style="display:table; font-size:small;  margin-top:0px;  text-decoration:none; font-family: Arial; color:#16161D;"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#16161D">https:/URL-example.eu</font></span></a></td>  
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr  >
                        <td><a  href="mailto:email@URL-example.eu"><span style=" display:table; font-size: small; text-decoration:none; font-family: Arial;"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#16161D";>email@URL-example.eu</font></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
    
    
                </table>    
    
                <table  align="left" width="100" cellpadding="2", cellspacing="" >
                    <tr align="left"> 
                        <td width="30"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ExampleName"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/f6DwyDA.png" alt="Example Name Facebook Account"></a></td>
                        <td width="35"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/ExampleName/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/BDQERsI.png" alt="Example Name Instagram Account"></a></td>
                        <td width="50"><a href="https://twitter.com/ExampleName"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Xx1atey.png" alt=Example Name Twitter Account"></a></td>     
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>               
    </table>
```

**Thank you for all your help.**

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with how you're adding the signature in Gmail.

The simplest method is to open your HTML + CSS in a webpage (you can even use the Stack Snippet you shared just full screen it) and hit ctrl/cmd + A to select all the content on the page it should highlight all in blue including images. Then hit ctrl/cmd + C to copy it to clipboard and just paste it into the signature field in Gmail. Your code works fine if you do the above.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate this in a Gmail test. Should be fine - but check @JHeth's answer.

Nevertheless, I also found a slight difference on Outlook iOS, as it added a line-height:150% to the `<font>` and `<a>` tags. There are often defaults like this, so it's best to always specify font-size and line-height for `<font>` and `<p>` and `<a>` tags, and there will also be colour and text-decoration defaults for `<a>`.

For block elements there are default margins and paddings.

So that's how you will get consistency, by adding a HTML-email equivalent CSS reset (note it has to be inline like you've done here, as opposed to `<style>`).